# I can't figure out this query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am a beginner at SQL. I am trying to write a query which "provides the  Total salary drawn by all people for each department if the total salary is greater than 300,000".
I have written some of it, but can't figure it out completely.

```
USE EMP_DB_01;
SELECT DEPTNAME, SUM(SALARY) AS 'Total Salary'
FROM DEPT, EMP 
WHERE (SALARY > 300000) AND (DEPT.DEPTNO = EMP.DEPTNO)
GROUP BY DEPTNAME
```

Table is here 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQqPw.png)

Comment: You can't simply use comma(,) and get data from multiple tables. You should use JOIN to get data from multiple tables in SQL.

Comment: @MurtuzaKhan duly noted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a join between the DEPT and EMP could be based on DEPT.DEPTNO = EMP.DEPTNO ..and for total salary is greater than 300,000  you should use having and not where

Having filter the result of aggregated  result ..  where filter the rows values

this return the dept and the  the related  Total Salary when the sum is > 300.00

```
USE EMP_DB_01;
SELECT DEPTNAME, SUM(SALARY) AS 'Total Salary'
FROM DEPT
INNER JOIN  EMP ON DEPT.DEPTNO = EMP.DEPTNO
HAVING  SUM(SALARY) > 300000
GROUP BY DEPTNAME
```

Comment: i think also SUM(SALARY) > 300000

Comment: @sami .. you have and error?  explain what do you mean with  "didn't work "

Comment: @scaisEdge I am not getting any error, but the answer is not right. The executed query is showing nothing except column names.

Comment: check better because based on the sample provided should retunr dept 20 ... check if you have proper data ..

Comment: yes, but it's not giving me anything. I have double checked my data, and it's fine.

Comment: I don't see error  .. and looking to you data must return dept 20 .. ..update you question and  post you real data  .. and not image  ..  or buil d proper sqlfilddle ..

Comment: It worked, thanks. It turns out I was using another database, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Sami   .. I was just about to ask you if you were using the right database

Comment: @scaisEdge  haha